# Can't get css height to propogate to Bootstrap row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to setup a 3 panel HTML view. (Full-height Treeview left, Editor and Status stacked to the right.) I can get it to work no problem in vanilla CSS, but I've spend a day at it in Bootstrap 4. I've followed much of the advice on here, but no joy. My left column stays small. I will paste my HTML and CSS below, and a screen shot of the failed result. Any help appreciated - I think I am getting too old for this :-)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .body {
    display: table;
    background-color: green;
}

  
  .min-100 {
      min-height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cc.css">
  </head>

  <div class="container-fluid min-100">
      <div class="row min-100">
        <clientArea class="col-sm-3 flex-grow-1 min-100" style="background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid">
          <h1>Client Treeview area</h1>
          <p>This will contain a list of Clients, Premises, Zones and Sensors</p>
        </clientArea>
        <editArea class="col-sm-9" style="background-color: white; border:1px solid">
          <h1>Editor area</h1>
        </editArea>
        <statusArea class="col-sm-9 offset-3" style="background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid">
          <h1>Status area</h1>
        </statusArea>
      </div>
  </div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit to the `bootstrap` logic your editor and status area need to be in the same `col`. The use of `vh` unit make the element fit the full height of your screen. Try this example on **full page**:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.body {
  display: table;
  background-color: green;
}

.vh-100 {
  height: 100vh;
}

.min-100 {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cc.css">
  </head>

  <div class="container-fluid min-100">
    <div class="row min-100">
      <clientArea class="col-sm-3 vh-100 flex-grow-1 min-100" style="background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid">
        <h1>Client Treeview area</h1>
        <p>This will contain a list of Clients, Premises, Zones and Sensors</p>
      </clientArea>

      <section class="col-sm-9 vh-100">
        <editArea class="" style="background-color: white; border:1px solid">
          <h1>Editor area</h1>
        </editArea>
        <statusArea class="" style="background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid">
          <h1>Status area</h1>
        </statusArea>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Johann. <Section> and ".vh-100" (and indeed vh-xx) were most enlightening. I've pretty much avoided any browser-based code for over 40 years now, but I have to say I'm beginning to like it - but there is so very much to read.

Comment: @Greycon Be aware ! `.vh-100` is only a self-written class to use a `css` rule: `height: 100vh`. It is written in the css ;) If it has solved your problem can you please `validate` my answer ;)

Comment: Yes indeed, I saw that - I had to modify my own CSS. Done.